# How to solve java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field Companion of type Landroidx/compose/runtime/SlotTable$Companion?

Tags: android-studio, android-jetpack, material-components-android, android-jetpack-navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I am getting this error multiple times in all my Jetpack compose projects. Is this error an issue related to the Gradle? Because I have not changed anything to the Theme.

```java
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field Companion of type Landroidx/compose/runtime/SlotTable$Companion; in class Landroidx/compose/runtime/SlotTable; or its superclasses (declaration of 'androidx.compose.runtime.SlotTable' appears in /data/app/~~-cK_xmGsJokhf6B_7aQseg==/com.swetajain.library-CN37OSea3A4uAWXYCBb63w==/base.apk)
```

[image: Logs]

app.build.gradle

```
dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation-layout:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$compose_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:compose-theme-adapter:$compose_version"
    api 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.0-beta01@aar'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.2.0-beta01@aar'
    implementation "dev.chrisbanes.accompanist:accompanist-coil:0.3.3.1"
    def nav_compose_version = "1.0.0-alpha02"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$nav_compose_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

build.gradle -Project

```
buildscript {

    ext.compose_version = '1.0.0-alpha04'
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.20"

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0-alpha16"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

[image: gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties]

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Android Studio Canary & Compose?

Comment: Yes, I am using compose_version 1.0.0-alpha04

Comment: i suggest you should post your dependencies too

Comment: did you tried by changing version of composer `1.0.0-alpha04` to `1.0.0-alpha08`

Comment: is this initially when you started a new project or did you add anything else? Also update as Wini said

Comment: Pretty sure only Compose `1.0.0-alpha08` is compatible with Kotlin `1.4.20`

Comment: @PeterHaddad It happens when I try to add a dependency in the build.gradle, like when I try to add the dependency for Coil Image

Comment: @Wini IDE did not prompt me for the 1.0.0-alpha08, it prompts for 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT, why is that so ?

Comment: @SwetaJain i just addded your whole gradle in my project well it does prompt me `A newer version of androidx.compose.ui:ui than 1.0.0-alpha07 is available: 1.0.0-alpha08`

Comment: @Wini ok, I will try again

Comment: Post your gradle.properties

Comment: org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
# org.gradle.parallel=true
android.useAndroidX=true
kotlin.code.style=official

Answer (score 1):

Try to update your compose version to the latest if you see such error.
[java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field Companion of type Landroidx/compose/foundation/layout/BoxScope$Companion;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67073647/java-lang-nosuchfielderror-no-field-companion-of-type-landroidx-compose-foundat/67122959#67122959)

Answer (score 0):

If you use binding and change component from XML for example if you add Button after that changed to EditText It will through that exception. Just you need to do rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but after updating all AndroidX libraries to the latest, the issue was gone.