# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field Companion of type Landroidx/compose/foundation/layout/BoxScope$Companion;

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-scaffold

I'm using Jetpack Compose for the first time but I'm getting this error. I haven't figured out where the problem really is but I'm using single-activity architecture. If more information is needed, kindly inform me.
According to the error, the problem seems to be coming from the Scaffold.

```kotlin
                val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()

                Scaffold(
                    scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
                    snackbarHost = {
                        SnackbarHost(hostState = it)
                    }
                ) {
```

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field Companion of type Landroidx/compose/foundation/layout/BoxScope$Companion; in class Landroidx/compose/foundation/layout/BoxScope; or its superclasses (declaration of 'androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxScope' appears in /data/app/com.octagon_technologies.scafe-0B8-dDpbnRqa6fydxFPekw==/base.apk)
        at androidx.compose.material.SurfaceKt$Surface$1.invoke(Surface.kt:149)
        at androidx.compose.material.SurfaceKt$Surface$1.invoke(Surface.kt:105)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:193)
        at androidx.compose.material.SurfaceKt.Surface-F-jzlyU(Surface.kt:102)
        at androidx.compose.material.ScaffoldKt$Scaffold$child$1.invoke(Scaffold.kt:168)
        at androidx.compose.material.ScaffoldKt$Scaffold$child$1.invoke(Scaffold.kt:167)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:118)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.material.ScaffoldKt.Scaffold-J67Y1T8(Scaffold.kt:197)
        at com.octagon_technologies.scafe.presentation.MainActivity$onCreate$1$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:54)
        at com.octagon_technologies.scafe.presentation.MainActivity$onCreate$1$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:47)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:193)
        at androidx.compose.material.TextKt.ProvideTextStyle(Text.kt:246)
        at androidx.compose.material.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:78)
        at androidx.compose.material.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:77)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:193)
        at androidx.compose.material.MaterialThemeKt.MaterialTheme(MaterialTheme.kt:69)
        at com.octagon_technologies.scafe.presentation.ui.theme.ThemeKt.ScafeTheme(Theme.kt:46)
        at com.octagon_technologies.scafe.presentation.MainActivity$onCreate$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:47)
        at com.octagon_technologies.scafe.presentation.MainActivity$onCreate$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:46)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView.Content(ComposeView.android.kt:346)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:202)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:201)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
```

Comment: Make sure that you are pulling in a consistent set of Compose dependencies. `beta04` made a change to `BoxScope` in the `compose-foundation` artifact. Perhaps you are getting `beta04` of that artifact but are getting an older `compose-material` artifact.

Comment: I'm facing the same error trying to use a Card() composable, have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is based on CommonsWare comment which helped me fix the error.

The solution was to use a consistent set of Compose dependencies. beta04 made a change to BoxScope in the compose-foundation artifact. Perhaps you are getting beta04 of that artifact but are getting an older compose-material artifact.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error and solved it by updating the compose version. The new project template generated by Android Studio comes with compose version `1.0.0-beta01`

Open build.gradle file and update

```
compose_version = '1.0.0-beta05'
```

or newer if you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error after adding `androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha10` as a dependency.

What worked for me was to downgrade to `androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha09`.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error for this code

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: 
No static field Companion of type Landroidx/compose/foundation/layout/BoxScope$Companion; 
in class Landroidx/compose/foundation/layout/BoxScope; 
or its superclasses (declaration of 'androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxScope' 
appears in /data/app/ink.iamt.demo-l1DoSMoQUFGcF5KYI5RU0w==/base.apk)
```

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Card {
                Text("Hello, Compose")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You know my code cannot be simpler. So I thought it should not be my fault.
I checked my Android Studio version, it's 2020.3.1 Canary 14, which is the latest version. And checked the build.gradle for Jetpack compose, it's

```
    val compose_version by extra("1.0.0-beta01")
```

So the latest Android Studio creates a new Compose project with 1.0.0-beta01 compose version, while the latest compose version is 1.0.0-beta04. Then I try to update the version to beta04 and rerun my App. Then it works!

**So please try to update your compose version to the latest and see if you have the luck.**